# Is applying AI ok and/or practical to finding the optimal solution to the algorithmic problem

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, abstraction

Both in learning environment and practice, from time to time I had to use different algorithms to solve problems. But the more I use them, the more it seems like the AI could be deployed to try finding the optimal solution, especially to the NP-complete problems, since the AI "progression" is easily tracked

If we, for example, never knew how to solve knapsack problem efficiently; I wonder, is applying AI practical and/or ever OK to finding the optimal solution to the given problem?

Comment: for some problems like the fractional knapsack we can prove that our algorithm is optimal. for other problems (like NP) its very common to use ML to try to find a practical model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AI algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence#Basics) in general can find an approximation to basically any function. They are so powerful because this is true even for extremely complex functions with many input parameters and/or many output parameters and/or a very complicated internal structure.

On the other hand, there is no known way to solve [NP-complete problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) "quickly". In practice, you would often have to search through a huge solution space for finding the optimal solution. This is why people use heuristic methods and approximation algorithms to efficiently find a "sufficiently good" solution.

So yes, you can use AI to find a good approximate solution (and possibly even a better one than with traditional heuristics) to a computationally hard problem.

But no, if the problem is NP-complete, you still cannot know that you have found the optimal solution.

Comment: Does this mean that if the problem isn't NP-complete, deploying AI isn't worth it?

Comment: This really depends on the problem: If there is an efficient solution algorithm, it does in fact not make much sense to apply an AI method. However, for many real-world applications you may not know if they are reducible to some standard problem. AI methods are often appropriate when you cannot easily find a closed-form solution, regardless of the complexity class.